# Calendar Javascript Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have managed to create a javascript dropdown using the following fiddle:

```
(function() {
    var calendar = [
        ["January", 31],
        ["February", 28],
        ["March", 31],
        ["April", 30],
        ["May", 31],
        ["June", 30],
        ["July", 31],
        ["August", 31],
        ["September", 30],
        ["October", 31],
        ["November", 30],
        ["December", 31]
        ],
        cont = document.getElementById('calendar-container');
    // setup
    var sel_year = document.createElement('select'),
        sel_month = document.createElement('select'),
        sel_day = document.createElement('select');

    function createOption(txt, val) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = val;
        option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
        return option;
    }

    function clearChildren(ele) {
        while (ele.hasChildNodes()) {
            ele.removeChild(ele.lastChild);
        }
    }

    function recalculateDays() {
        var month_index = sel_month.value,
            df = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var i = 0, l = calendar[month_index][1]; i < l; i++) {
            df.appendChild(createOption(i + 1, i));
        }
        clearChildren(sel_day);
        sel_day.appendChild(df);
    }

    function generateMonths() {
        var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
        calendar.forEach(function(info, i) {
            df.appendChild(createOption(info[0], i));
        });
        clearChildren(sel_month);
        sel_month.appendChild(df);
    }

    sel_month.onchange = recalculateDays;

    generateMonths();
    recalculateDays();

    cont.appendChild(sel_year);
    cont.appendChild(sel_month);
    cont.appendChild(sel_day);
}());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/j2kzv/

However I would like to modify it to display the current month and date by default. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this would work: http://jsfiddle.net/j2kzv/24/

I didn't change much just added checking against the current date as you create the options:

```
calendar.forEach(function(info, i) {
            var selected = (currentDate.getMonth() === i) ? true : false;
            df.appendChild(createOption(info[0], i, selected));
});
```

Then added a selected check when building out each option.

```
function createOption(txt, val, selected) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = val;
    option.selected = selected;
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
    return option;
}
```

I also updated the date function for loop to use ordinal 1 for the checkbox values rather than 0 for simplicity sake